# Toolbar functional, but text/settings icon not visible in Fragment on Kit Kat

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat, android-toolbar

I've read over a fair few other threads regarding this issue, but have not been able to work out my problem. On Android 5.x my app works fine. But when testing on Android 4.4 Kit Kat I have an issue.

**Problem:**
- My toolbar/action bar is functional, and still works however the activity name text and the hamburger menu item does not display. I have attached images below to demonstrate the problem.

[image]
[image]

I have a main activity, with a nav bar and each item on the nav bar loads a new fragment. I am using the below setup for fragment definition.

`public class <ClassName> extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {}`

I have attached my 2 x styles XML files & my main fragment file, but i'm not sure if that is where the problem lies. I have also tried removing all content in the layout on the affected screen but that hasn't helped either. This is my first time trying to get layout issues fixed across older version of Android so i'm a tad lost.

Do I need to create a new toolbar object?

**values/styles.xml**

```xml
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
   </style>

   <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
       <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   </style>

   <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
   <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/whiteSystem</item>
        <item name="tabTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**v21/styles.xml**

```xml
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
   </style>

    <style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/whiteSystem</item>
        <item name="tabTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Fragment class which is having the issue**

```java
import android.app.Activity;
//import android.app.Fragment;
//import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class ParentFragment extends Fragment {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    private View myFragmentView; //this will enable 'findviewbyid' to be accessed

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parentFragment, container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdaptor(getChildFragmentManager(), getActivity()));

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
        });

        return myFragmentView;
    }

    private class CustomAdaptor extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private String fragments[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};

        public CustomAdaptor(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Activity activity) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new FragmentOne();
                case 1:
                    return new FragmentTwo();
                case 2:
                    return new FragmentThree();
                case 3:
                    return new FragmentFour();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return fragments[position];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, i've done a little research over the weekend. I messed around with the 'alpha' setting of the fragments layout xml file and it appears it was an overlapping issue, hence why the nav drawer would work when the hamburger icon was tapped but I couldn't see it. 

I went through some navigation drawer tutorials on youtube again, and it appears to be due to me not using a framelayout as a container for my fragments. I used this tutorial to help me in case anyone else is interested.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tguOfRD8vYo&index=1&list=FL67XN3ZqRdHqNjzbSHDv96A